# Regarding Emails in Tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, tracking

In salesforce marketing cloud ,is it true that if we do not move the recent email send that was done from tracking to a different folder, that the new set of emails send from the same location will be affected?

For Eg, Imagine last week I sent an user initiated email and it is placed in My Tracking --> Test(a folder)
I don't remove this email or move it anywhere and again I send another user initiated email (with the same email address of last week) from the same location, Tracking --> Test and will this affect the number of emails sent or received?

Comment: Where did you get this info from?

Comment: How would this be affected when each send has a unique job ID?